# WCF Service-Consumer Syncrohnisation

Tags: c#, wcf, synchronization

I am trying to synchronise changes to a `DataContract` between my service and it's consumers. I am having trouble designing a maintainable way of informing of property changes.

For example, I want to keep the below synchronised:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyObject
{
    [DataMember]
    public Guid Id { get; private set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

    [DataMember]
    public int Foo { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

My original approach was to use an event which took a property name and an object, as such:

```
public delegate void PropertyChangedEventHandler(Guid id, string propertyName, object value);
```

The service & consumers could then subscribe to the property changes:

```
myObject.PropertyChanged += MyObjectPropertyChanged;

// MyObject would raise the property change inside of the property set.

private void MyObjectPropertyChanged(Guid id, string propertyName, object value)
{
    // Depending on which end is listening the service can send
    // the change to the consumer or vica versa
}
```

I have encountered an issue using this method as the serializer could not determine how to serialize `object`.

I now don't know how to handle informing of changes. I can see two approaches but I am hoping for a better solution.

I could inform the consumer/service that a change has been made. It can then request from the service/consumer for the changed `MyObject`. I see this being a problem if more than one consumer changes the same object at the same time (as the service is concurrency is set to multiple). It could result in one consumer's changes being lost.

The second approach is to create an `EventArgs`, which mirrors the properties of the `MyObject` and you access the property based on the property name passed with the `EventArgs` and synchronise the local copy. This would allow two consumers to change different properties without fear of either being lost. However this feels like a lot of repeated code. A lot of unused data is also passed around as `MyObject` grows. Admitidly there is room for reflection in regards to reading and setting the appropriate property.

For example:

```
public class MyObjectPropertyChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }

    // Then one of the relative property below would be set to the new value
    public int Foo { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

I don't see this being an uncommon use case and was hoping for some insight into how this is usually done?

Answer (score 0):

As far as service is concerned, why do not you leverage of *CallbackContract* in order to notify client that some changes occured? 
On client side in turn DataContract can implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface and whenever change to any property takes place then you call service.

Comment: I am using `CallbackContract`. What I am having troubles with is deciding how to notify of changes in an extensible and maintainable way. Adding a method per property on the `CallbackContract` change isn't extensible as any additional propertys added down the line would require a new method which would break the client.

Comment: Create enum in which you enlist properties and in callback method add aditional parameter of type enum indicating which property is supposed to be notified about change.